# GIS network tracing - water network

Tags: network, geometric-network, tracing

I have been trying to find out if it is possible to trace through a water network that will consist of line features representing water mains. Tools exist in both QGIS and ArcGIS to help with this and I can set start, end, and barriers

Does anyone know if it is possible to use an attribute value in another feature i.e. 'closed' in a Valves feature, for example, to act as a barrier that the network tracing functionality would recognize? Often valves are maintained in a closed position to assist with water network operations and management and it would be useful to be able to somehow read that status of a valve when carrying out a network trace

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in ArcGIS this should be pretty straight forward. You need to do a select (Select Layer by Attributes) on your other feature layer to select all the 'closed' valves. You then pass in that layer to your barriers parameter on the Trace tool. The tool should honor and use *only* the selected features.

Comment: thanks @KHibma I will try that in ArcGIS. I would also like to find a coding way to do this either in something like QGIS or NetworkX perhaps but my coding skills are a little basic and I need some pointers if possible

Comment: If you're looking for a code solution to a specific software, I'd suggest taking a shot at it (writing the code best you can), then posting a specific question describing the problem with your code and that particular software (ie. focus the question to what should be a single answer)